# Problema en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un formulario de login bastante sencillo, el problema radica en que sino coloco usuario y contraseña entra sin problema, pero si coloco el usuario y la contraseña, me coloca el alert de que su usuario será bloqueado. Les dejo el codigo completo a ver si alguno me podria ayudar a solucionar esto. ¡Gracias!

```
<body>
<script>
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var clave = document.getElementById('clave').value;
    function validacion (){    
        if (nombre != "Banking" || password != "1234") {
            alert ("su portal ha sido bloqueado por razones de seguridad");
        }
        else
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
    } 
</script>
<div class="login__container">
    <form class="login__form" onsubmit= "return validacion()">
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="&#128100; usuario" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" id="clave" placeholder="&#x1F512; password" required>
        <input class="btn__submit" type="submit" value="ENTRAR" onclick="location.href='index.html'">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Saludos, si vas a usar los {} para el if, el else también debe llevarlos.

Comment: password nunca es usado, te dará un error de undefined, estás usando la variable clave..... Hay muchas cosas que no encajan, pon el código que estás usando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("entrar").addEventListener("click",   validacion);    
  function validacion (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var clave = document.getElementById('clave').value; 
    if (nombre != "Banking" || clave != "1234") {
        alert ("su portal ha sido bloqueado por razones de seguridad");
    }else{
          window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }

  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="login__container">
        <form class="login__form">
            <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="&#128100; usuario" required autofocus>
            <input type="password" id="clave" placeholder="&#x1F512; password" required>
            <input class="btn__submit" type="submit" value="ENTRAR" id="entrar">
        </form>
    </div>
```

El problema es que te intenta pillar el usuario y la contraseña nada más cargar el documento, mientras esta vacio, hay que controlarlo y tener cuidado. Lo segundo es que en vez de clave pusiste password. Aqui tienes un ejemplo completamente funcional. Si tienes alguna duda, pregunta!

**Aqui te dejo la versión con tu código**

```js
function validacion() {
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var clave = document.getElementById('clave').value;
    if (nombre != "Banking" || clave != "1234") {
        alert("su portal ha sido bloqueado por razones de seguridad");
        return false;
    } else {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="login__container">
    <form class="login__form" onsubmit="return validacion();">
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="&#128100; usuario" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" id="clave" placeholder="&#x1F512; password" required>
        <input class="btn__submit" type="submit" value="ENTRAR">
    </form>
</div>
```

Lo unico que se tiene que quitar es e onclick ya he obliga si o si redireccionar a index. Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Este no es el formulario que ha puesto el usuario para su ejercicio. por tanto, no tendrías que parar el evento submit, simplemente comprobar y retornar un false, sino se cumple, el formulario no se enviará. (hay un onsubmit en el <form)

Comment: esta parado para poder hacer pruebas sin que recargue la pagina, igualmente ahora lo arreglo

Comment: ¡Gracias ivan! ya entendí lo que estaba haciendo mal y lo correjí... aprender JavaScript es un tanto complejo

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirviera! Igualmente más tarde lo dejo como tu lo necesitabas, con el submit!

Comment: @alearmas ya está añadida la otra opción! Revisala, es más fácil de ver.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer es agregar los {} al else, esto podría causarte conflictos si no lo tiene, el siguiente paso es meter los value de JS dentro de la función, ya que al tenerlas fuera, los valores no se asignan, otra cosa es que tenias la validación hacia la variable password debe ser la variable clave

```js
    
    function validacion (){    
        var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
        var clave = document.getElementById('clave').value;
        if (nombre != "Banking" || clave != "1234") {
            alert ("su portal ha sido bloqueado por razones de seguridad");
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="login__container">
    <form class="login__form" onsubmit= "return validacion()">
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="&#128100; usuario" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" id="clave" placeholder="&#x1F512; password" required>
        <input class="btn__submit" type="submit" value="ENTRAR" onclick="location.href='index.html'">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Los princpales problemas son:

1. Definiste `clave` pero luego comprobabas la inexistente variable `password`
2. Cogías el valor de los elementos nombre y clave fuera de la función, así que independientemente de los valores que escribieses, los valores siempre serían los iniciales.

```
<script>
    function validacion (){    
        var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
        var clave = document.getElementById('clave').value;
        if (nombre != "Banking" || clave != "1234") {
            alert ("su portal ha sido bloqueado por razones de seguridad");
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Además, recomendaría aprovechar el potencial de JS y no hacer referencias a elementos de la DOM siempre que se pueda evitar:

```
<form class="login__form" onsubmit= "return validacion(this)">

function validacion (form){    
    var nombre = form.nombre.value;
    var clave = form.clave.value;
    if (nombre != "Banking" || clave != "1234") {
        alert ("su portal ha sido bloqueado por razones de seguridad");
    }
    else{
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }
}
```

Comment: igualmente no arregla el problema de que entra sin meter ni contraseña, ni usuario